# Error Angular 13: ngForOf not used by any directive... Can't bind to 'ngForOf'

Tags: angular, typescript, visual-studio-code, angular13

I am getting this error

> ```
> Property binding ngForOf not used by any directive on an embedded template. Make sure that the property name is spelled correctly and all directives are listed in the "@NgModule.declarations". >
> ```
>
> Can't bind to 'ngForOf' since it isn't a known property of 'a'

I already imported all necessary modules:  *CommonModule*, *BrowserModule*, *ReactiveFormsModule*

app.module.ts :

```
import { CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { RecipesComponent } from './components/recipes/recipes.component';
import { RecipeListComponent } from './components/recipes/recipe-list/recipe-list.component';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HeaderComponent,
    RecipesComponent,
    RecipeListComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    CommonModule,
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
  schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

recipe-list.component.ts :

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12">
    <a href="#" class="list-group-item clearfix" *ngFor="let recipe of recipes"> // error ngFor
      <div class="pull-left">
        <h4 class="list-group-item-heading"> {{ recipe.name}} </h4>
      </div>
      <span class="pull-right">
        <img [src]="recipe.imagePath" alt=" {{recipe.name}} " srcset="" class="img-responsive" style="max-height: 50px">
      </span>
    </a>
    <app-recipe-item></app-recipe-item>
  </div>
</div>
```

I'm using Angular v13.1.1 / Node v16.13.1 / VSCode v1.63.2

[image: screen of my error]

Comment: BTW, project work fine but the error still appears

Comment: Remove `schemas` as a prop of `ngModule`. It causes the error.

Comment: You don't need about schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA]

Comment: Error still appears, i removed had  schemas and uninstall VS code and reinstall it but no result !

Answer (score 5):

Disabling the Visual Studio extension "Angular Language Service" solved the problem.

Comment: super thanks mate, I was so confused why all of sudden this error showed up.
I even started a new Angular Project and got the same issue.

Comment: You're welcome!

Comment: Thanks man, this was giving me a headache already...